# GTK+ change font to spin button

Tags: c, gtk

I created a spin button in GTK+ like this:

```
flow_spin = gtk_spin_button_new_with_range (100,1500,25);
```

and I want to change it's font and size. I googled in order to find a workaround because it seems that the spin button widget doesn't change it's format natively, but nothing worked.

This:

```
flow_spin.Child.ModifyFont(FontDescription.FromString("Courier 16"));
```

as well as this, didn't work:

```
flow_spin.Markup = "<span size='38000'>big text</span>";
```

As for this, the plus and minus buttons got bigger, but the text area remained the same size:

```
gtk_widget_set_size_request ( flow_spin,50, 50);
```

I look if possibly for a method, similar to this ?

```
gtk_label_set_markup (GTK_LABEL (label), "<span font='8' foreground='black' weight='normal'>100</span>");
```

Since I am a beginner at C as well as GTK+, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Gtk supports CSS for styling. You can load a CSS file in your program with `gtk_css_provider_load_from_file()`.

So, just add a style provider on GtkWidget you want to stylish.

It's good read:

- https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/theming.html
- https://thegnomejournal.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/styling-gtk-with-css/

Comment: I think it's better to read the official documentation chapter about CSS at  https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/theming.html . A blog post from 6 years ago, while the CSS theming implementation only has been stable for around 1 year won't have all the quirks explained.

Comment: @liberforce If you read the blog you will see that it just show how to use css flags with gtk (it never change since 6 years ago), and everyone knows how to find the documentation. But no problem, I've added the link.